# Testing for Adjacent Cells In a Multi-level Grid

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, recursion, gis

I'm designing an algorithm to test whether cells on a grid are adjacent or not.
The catch is that the cells are not on a flat grid.  They are on a multi-level grid such as the one drawn below.

```
Level 1 (Top Level)
| - - - - - |
| A | B | C |
| - - - - - |
| D | E | F |
| - - - - - |
| G | H | I |
| - - - - - |


Level 2
| -Block A- | -Block B- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| - - - - - | - - - - - |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 6 |   ...
| - - - - - | - - - - - |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| - - - - - | - - - - - |
| -Block D- | -Block E- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| - - - - - | - - - - - |
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 5 | 6 |   ...
| - - - - - | - - - - - |
| 7 | 8 | 9 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| - - - - - | - - - - - |
      .           .
      .           .
      .           .
```

This diagram is simplified from my actual need but the concept is the same.  There is a top level block with many cells within it (level 1).  Each block is further subdivided into many more cells (level 2).  Those cells are further subdivided into level 3, 4 and 5 for my project but let's just stick to two levels for this question.

I'm receiving inputs for my function in the form of "A8, A9, B7, D3".  That's a list of cell Ids where each cell Id has the format (level 1 id)(level 2 id).

Let's start by comparing just 2 cells, A8 and A9.  That's easy because they are in the same block.

```
private static RelativePosition getRelativePositionInTheSameBlock(String v1, String v2) {
    RelativePosition relativePosition;

    if( v1-v2 == -1 ) {
        relativePosition = RelativePosition.LEFT_OF;
    }
    else if (v1-v2 == 1) {
        relativePosition = RelativePosition.RIGHT_OF;
    }
    else if (v1-v2 == -BLOCK_WIDTH) {
        relativePosition = RelativePosition.TOP_OF;
    }
    else if (v1-v2 == BLOCK_WIDTH) {
        relativePosition = RelativePosition.BOTTOM_OF;
    }
    else {
        relativePosition = RelativePosition.NOT_ADJACENT;
    }
    return relativePosition;
}
```

An A9 - B7 comparison could be done by checking if A is a multiple of BLOCK_WIDTH and whether B is (A-BLOCK_WIDTH+1).
Either that or just check naively if the A/B pair is 3-1, 6-4 or 9-7 for better readability.

For B7 - D3, they are not adjacent but D3 is adjacent to A9 so I can do a similar adjacency test as above.

So getting away from the little details and focusing on the big picture.  Is this really the best way to do it?  Keeping in mind the following points:

- I actually have 5 levels not 2, so I could potentially get a list like "A8A1A, A8A1B, B1A2A, B1A2B".
- Adding a new cell to compare still requires me to compare all the other cells before it (seems like the best I could do for this step
  is O(n))
- The cells aren't all 3x3 blocks, they're just that way for my example.  They could be MxN blocks with different M and N for
  different levels.
- In my current implementation above, I have separate functions to check adjacency if the cells are in the same blocks, if they are in
  separate horizontally adjacent blocks or if they are in separate
  vertically adjacent blocks. That means I have to know the position of
  the two blocks at the current level before I call one of those
  functions for the layer below.

Judging by the complexity of having to deal with mulitple functions for different edge cases at different levels and having 5 levels of nested if statements.  I'm wondering if another design is more suitable.  Perhaps a more recursive solution, use of other data structures, or perhaps map the entire multi-level grid to a single-level grid (my quick calculations gives me about 700,000+ atomic cell ids).  Even if I go that route, mapping from multi-level to single level is a non-trivial task in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - I actually have 5 levels not 2, so I could potentially get a list like "A8A1A, A8A1B, B1A2A, B1A2B".
> - Adding a new cell to compare still requires me to compare all the other cells before it (seems like the best I could do for this step is
>     O(n))
> - The cells aren't all 3x3 blocks, they're just that way for my example. They could be MxN blocks with different M and N for different
>     levels.

I don't see a problem with these points: if a cell is not adjacent at the highest level one then we can stop the computation right there and we don't have to compute adjacency at the lower levels. If there are only five levels then you'll do at most five adjacency computations which should be fine.

> - In my current implementation above, I have separate functions to check adjacency if the cells are in the same blocks, if they are in separate horizontally adjacent blocks or if they are in separate vertically adjacent blocks. That means I have to know the position of the two blocks at the current level before I call one of those functions for the layer below.

You should try to rewrite this. There should only be two methods: one that computes whether two cells are adjacent and one that computes whether two cells are adjacent at a given level:

- `RelativePosition isAdjacent(String cell1, String cell2);`
- `RelativePosition isAdjacentAtLevel(String cell1, String cell2, int level);`

The method `isAdjacent` calls the method `isAdjacentAtLevel` for each of the levels. I'm not sure whether `cell1` or `cell2` always contain information of all the levels but `isAdjacent` could analyze the given cell strings and call the appropriate level adjacency checks accordingly. When two cells are not adjacent at a particular level then all deeper levels don't need to be checked.

The method `isAdjacentAtLevel` should do: lookup *M* and *N* for the given level, extract the information from `cell1` and `cell2` of the given level and perform the adjacency computation. The computation should be the same for each level as each level, on its own, has the same block structure.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate and compare the absolute x and y coordinate for the lowest level.

For the example (assuming `int index0` = 0 for A, 1 for B, ... and `index1` = 0...8):

```
int x = (index0 % 3) * 3 + index1 % 3;
int y = (index0 / 3) * 3 + index1 / 3;
```

In general, given

```
int[] WIDTHS;   // cell width at level i  
int[] HEIGHTS;  // cell height at level i

// indices: cell index at each level, normalized to 0..WIDTH[i]*HEIGHT[i]-1
int getX (int[] indices) {
  int x = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
     x = x * WIDTHS[i] + indices[i] % WIDTHS[i];
  }
  return x;
}

int getY (int[] indices) {
  int y = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
     y = y * HEIGHTS[i] + indices[i] / WIDTHS[i];
  }
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a space filling curve, for example a peano curve or z morton curve.